# Horrible Oracle update performance

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, sql-update

I am performing an update with a query like this:

```
UPDATE (SELECT     h.m_id,
                   m.id
        FROM       h
        INNER JOIN m
        ON         h.foo = m.foo)
SET    m_id = id
WHERE  m_id IS NULL
```

Some info:

- Table `h` is roughly ~5 million rows
- All rows in table `h` have `NULL` values for `m_id`
- Table `m` is roughly ~500 thousand rows
- `m_id` on table `h` is an indexed foreign key pointing to `id` on table `m`
- `id` on table `m` is the primary key
- There are indexes on `m.foo` and `h.foo`

The `EXPLAIN PLAN` for this query indicated a hash join and full table scans, but I'm no DBA, so I can't really interpret it very well.

The query itself ran for several hours and did not complete.  I would have expected it to complete in no more than a few minutes.  I've also attempted the following query rewrite:

```
UPDATE h
SET    m_id = (SELECT id
               FROM   m
               WHERE  m.foo = h.foo)
WHERE  m_id IS NULL
```

The `EXPLAIN PLAN` for this mentioned ROWID lookups and index usage, but it also went on for several hours without completing.  I've also always been under the impression that queries like this would cause the subquery to be executed for every result from the outer query's predicate, so I would expect very poor performance from this rewrite anyway.

*Is there anything wrong with my approach, or is my problem related to indexes, tablespace, or some other non-query-related factor?*

**Edit:**

I'm also having abysmal performance from simple count queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   h
WHERE  m_id IS NULL
```

These queries are taking anywhere from ~30 seconds to sometimes ~30 minutes(!).

I am noticing no locks, but the tablespace for these tables is sitting at 99.5% usage (only ~6MB free) right now.  I've been told that this shouldn't matter as long as indexes are being used, but I don't know...

Comment: Did you try to index `h.m_id` ?

Comment: @alfasin: Yes, I did, and it is now indexed, but the performance does not seem any different.

Comment: For bulk updates like this it's often quicker to SELECT into a new table and after it succeeds replace the current table with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points:

- Oracle does **not** index `NULL` values (it will index a `NULL` that is part of a globally non-null tuple, but that's about it).
- Oracle is going for a `HASH JOIN` because of the size of both `h` and `m`. This is likely the best option performance-wise.
- The second `UPDATE` *might* get Oracle to use indexes, but then Oracle is usually smart about merging subqueries. And it would be a worse plan anyway.
- Do you have recent, reasonable statistics for your schema? Oracle *really needs* decent statistics.
- In your execution plan, which is the first table in the `HASH JOIN`? For best performance it should be the smaller table (`m` in your case). If you don't have good cardinality statistics, Oracle will get messed up. You can force Oracle to assume fixed cardinalities with the `cardinality` hint, it may help Oracle get a better plan.

For example, in your first query:

```
UPDATE (SELECT /*+ cardinality(h 5000000) cardinality(m 500000) */
               h.m_id, m.id 
        FROM h 
        INNER JOIN m 
        ON h.foo = m.foo) 
SET m_id = id 
WHERE m_id IS NULL
```

- In Oracle, FULL SCAN reads not only every record in the table, it basically reads all *storage* allocated up to the maximum used (the *high water mark* in Oracle documentation). So if you have had a lot of deleted rows your tables might need some cleaning up. I have seen a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on an empty table consume 30+ seconds because the table in question had like 250 million deleted rows. If that is the case, I suggest analyzing your specific case with a DBA, so he/she can reclaim space from deleted rows and lower the *high water mark*.

Comment: Thank you for these tips; I learned a lot.  The smaller table is indeed listed in the `EXPLAIN PLAN` first.  I don't know anything about statistics or how to find out how many deleted rows, though, since I'm not a DBA (just a developer who recently lost both of his DBAs to retirement).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, a `WHERE m_id IS NULL` performs a full-table scan, since NULL values cannot be indexed.

Full-table scan means, that the engine needs to read every record in the table to evaluate the WHERE condition, and cannot use an index.

You could try to add a [virtual column](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/virtual-columns-in-oracle-11g/) set to a not-null value if `m_id IS NULL`, and index this column, and use this column in the WHERE condition.

Then you could also move the WHERE condition from the UPDATE statement to the sub-select, which will probably make the statement faster.

Since JOINs are expensive, rewriting `INNER JOIN m ON h.foo = m.foo` as

`WHERE h.foo IN (SELECT m.foo FROM m WHERE m.foo IS NOT NULL)`

may also help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these.  The `WHERE m_id IS NULL` condition is there because this query is run periodically, and I thought it would help performance by not updating rows that didn't need to be updated.  Would it be better to just update all rows every run?

Comment: removing that predicate would probably make it perform worse, since it will now be updating more rows.

Comment: The creation of a virtual column and updating it according to `m_id IS NULL` will be facing the same problem, no ?

Answer (score 1):

For large tables, MERGE is often much faster than UPDATE. Try this (untested):

```
MERGE INTO h USING
(SELECT     h.h_id,
            m.id as new_m_id
        FROM       h
        INNER JOIN m
        ON         h.foo = m.foo
 WHERE h.m_id IS NULL       
) new_data
ON (h.h_id = new_data.h_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET h.m_id = new_data.new_m_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would update the table in iterations, for example, add a condition according to `where h.date_created > sysdate-30` and after it finishes I would run the same query and change the condition to:  `where h.date_created between sysdate-30 and sysdate-60` etc. If you don't have a column like `date_created` maybe there's another column you can filter by ? for example: `WHERE  m.foo = h.foo AND m.foo between 1 and 10`

Only the result of `plan` can explain why the cost of this update is high, but an educated guess will be that both tables are very big and that there are many `NULL` values as well as a lot of matching (`m.foo = h.foo`)...

Comment: The `h.m_id` column is indexed already.  The 2nd suggestion helps somewhat, since at least the queries finish eventually, but still in way more time than should be needed (depending on the size of the "chunks").  Thank you for the suggestions, and I'll post the `EXPLAIN PLAN` when I can and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try **undocumented** hint /*+ BYPASS_UJVC */. If it works, add an UNIQUE/PK constraint on m.foo.